# Function returning the maximum area of a quadrilateral, given three parameters

Tags: geometry, optimization

Let $F$ be the function which, to any triplet of integers $(a, b, p)$ associates the maximum area of a quadrilateral with diagonals of length $a$ and $b$ and perimeter $p$, with $0 < b \leq a$ and
$$
2a < p < a + b + \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}. 
$$
Beyond this value (i.e. for
$$
a + b + \sqrt{a^2 + b^2} < p \leq 2(a + b), 
$$
limit value for a perimeter of a quadrilateral with diagonals $a$ and $b$ data), the function $F$ is poorly defined because the maximum area is then obtained for limiting configurations where the quadrilateral becomes a triangle, the diagonals having a common end.

Here are some values of $F$:
\begin{align}
F(3, 1, 7) &= \frac{3}{2}, \\
F(3, 2, 7) &= \frac{\sqrt{429}}{8}, \\
F(3, 2, 8) &= 3, \\
F(14, 11, 32) &= 45, \\
F(19, 14, 42) &= 70, \\
F(24, 15, 50) &= 70. 
\end{align}

Any idea to find $F(a,b,p)$?

Comment: It may simplify things to remove, say, the first variable, then normalize the quadrilateral so that the first diagonal is always 1. So you have $G(b,p)$ giving the max area of a quadrilateral with diagonals $1$ and $b$, and perimeter $p$.  You can recover $F$ from this by scaling, since $a^2\cdot G(\frac{b}{a},\frac{p}{a}) = F(a,b,p)$

Comment: After normalizing to $G$, think of the first diagonal as positioned on the $[0,1]$ segment of the $x$-axis.  To explore the "quadrilateral space" we have three degrees of freedom: move the point of intersection of the diagonals along $(0,1)$; allow the second diagonal to move vertically so that the ratio of its length above the $x$-axis is in $(0,1)$, and change the angle of intersection in $(0,\pi)$. Some symmetries can reduce further.  The quadrilaterals fulfilling the perimeter condition will be a 2D surface within this 3D space.  From there you may be able to use smooth manifold methods.

Comment: $$
F(a,b,p)=\cases{
{1\over2}ab & if $p\ge2\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$\cr
\cr
{1\over2}\sqrt{a^2 b^2 + p^4/16 - p^2 (a^2 + b^2)/4}
& if $p<2\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$\cr
}
$$

Comment: Great, that seems to work. I would love to know how you found these formulas. I thought that all this was based on the constraints of the integer values of the lengths of the diagonals and the perimeter without really finding a formula. I had clearly noted that for a certain example that F(a,b,p)= 1/2 a* b. This made me think of the formula for the lengths of diagonals by their angles when they are perpendicular. It is possible to have even a brief demonstration.

Comment: I'll give you an explanation if you want, but could you tell me how you got those values of $F$?